# Есть ли в php или в css функция которая ищет что-то в файлах

Tags: php, css, веб-программирование

есть ли в php или в css функция для поиска слов в несколько файлах

Comment: в css определённо нету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни в CSS, ни в PHP таких функций нет, но вы можете написать скрипт на PHP, который будет это делать.